# Alternatives to CSLA.NET?

Tags: .net, frameworks, enterprise

My company is evaluating [CSLA.NET](http://www.lhotka.net/Article.aspx?area=4&id=e6d603c6-9a1a-4a9f-94af-dcbb2f0a75d0) as a possible standard framework for all our .NET enterprise app development. For the sake of comparison, can anyone recommend some alternative frameworks in this space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with Neil in a general manner. You can also look at Windows Workflow and WCF which can be like a sort of role your own CSLA.NET.  Combined and/or mixed with other technologies like:

Persistance - OR/Ms:
Spring.NET, Entity Framework, NHibernate, LLBLGen, Enterprise Library, etc

Persistance NoSQL Solutions:
MongoDB, CoudhDB, Riak, Cassandra, RavenDB, Eloquera, db4o

DI/IoC: 
StructureMap, Ninject, Spring.NET, Enterprise Library

AOP: 
PostSharp, SNAP, Spring.NET

Combining these can make a very nice custom rolled solution that may not have a learning curve or bloat of CSLA and is very specific to your problem domain (DDD/CQRS can enter here).

But keep in mind DDD/CQRS can also be used with CSLA - but I prefer to use custom solutions as I think they are easier to get started with, maintain and troubleshoot.

Comment: None of these fill the space that Csla does, in fact you'd probably use one of those persistence solutions in combination with Csla.  None of those offer the same level of business rule support, you'd likely end up rolling you own.  Using Csla there's a chance a new hire has used Csla before, that number drops to 0 for a custom solution.

Comment: Actually @Andy they do when combined. Read what CSLA.NET is here: http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/Info.aspx and you will see that DI + POCOs and some design patterns (i.e. - decorator, command, repository) can handle everything CSLA does.  Loosely coupled apps can provide the same flexibility and even more as you're not confined to the concepts and idioms of CSLA. Rolling your own biz rules will abdsolutely provide the same level of support as CSLA if the developer wishes lol.  If a new hire is worth his salt it shouldn't be hard to understand how to use/implement the patterns I mentioned.

Comment: You miss my point; yes, you can roll your own framework using the technologies you mention, but just referencing them all in a project doesn't get you a business framework.  A new hire can certainly learn your custom framework, but why add more learning time for them to learn and become effective?  If you use ASP.net mvc and hire me, I already know that and dont need to learn all the idioms of it.  Role your own mvc framework and I have to learn that in addition to your actual application.

Comment: asp.net mvc is ubiquitous -CSLA.NET is not. I have not run across CSLA once in 15 years. CSLA isnt as common as MVC... therefore there will be a learning curve with CSLA or a custom solution.  Using the techniques I described its easy to create a clean, modern framework that does what CSLA does. Abstracting away the details is easily done once one fully understands design patterns. The consumer of a well defined Facade/Service should have no trouble at all. Think of the facebook/twitter, etc apis - not hard to learn and the implementation details are hidden.

Comment: btw - maybe you misunderstood my post... I wasn't talking about merely referencing other projects to do what CSLA does. The key point here, just as Neil suggested, are patterns. Repository (coupled w/ an ORM), Decorator (Validation/Biz Logic), Facade for Service layer, DI for loosely coupled/swappable components, etc. Its SUPER easy these days to implement. I just implemnted one in under a week which is easy to use. var user = IUserService.FindById(int id); user.Name = "me"; IUserService.Save(user);  -  Validation is done within the service. If a newbie cant figure that out dunno what 2 tel ya

Comment: Its interesting because I've interviewed for two jobs where they use Csla.  Its not as popular as mvc of course, but it is out there were a home grown solution is not.  The pool of Csla developers may be small, but the pool of new hires that will know the home grown solution is zero.  Creating a framework that does what Csla does will certainly be nontrivial as well, and sorry but twitters API is pretty trivial compared to what most business applications will need.  Just saying "use patterns" does not get a coherent solution upon which you can focus on business problems.

Comment: And I've spent quite a bit of time using those patterns in the way you suggest; the result is largely the anemic domain object antipattern, and its certainly not easier to maintain.  The patterns themselves are fine, but blindly implementing them as most do today creates a monstrosity of a system that is actually more costly in the long run.

Answer (score 5):

I think these days it's a good idea to question whether a business logic *framework* is really necessary. I think a pattern is more useful. I'm personally researching [Domain Driven Design](http://domaindrivendesign.org/) and [CQRS](http://cqrsinfo.com/documents/cqrs-introduction/), rather than buying into a framework/tool.

Comment: DDD by itself leaves you implementing much of the same things Csla would provide.  I'd also argue Csla and DDD in fact are very close, perhaps nit in exact implementation but the idea of rich models, bounded context etc are pretty much identical.

Answer (score 2):

[BLToolkit](http://www.bltoolkit.net/) works in roughly the same space.

Some [Enterprise Library](http://entlib.codeplex.com/) features overlap as well.